# Alexa voice to Python Based AI Model

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have a python file which takes voice input and runs a Tensor Flow model and recognizes weather it was a child or adult speaking.
can i use Alexa to sample voice and use the same voice as input to My python file

Answer (score 0):

Alexa does not give you the audio of your customer's speech.